# Filtering out unique rows on a CSV

Tags: python, csv

Please have a look at my sample code. State0 in my input.csv is 1101, state1 is 1100 and state2 is 100. What I want at the output is to write a single line which will pick one code in row[2] from each ID. Like from ID 1 it should pick 23456 and write it, from ID 2 it should pick 45632 and write it and from ID 3 it should pick 31276 and write it. I want to write a single line with all three codes for each ID. Currently after executing the code I get 23456 for ID 1 which is correct, 23412 for ID 2 which is wrong. It should be 45632 and for ID 3 it is writing a correct value of 31276. I want to write the first code only for each ID.
Out.CSV is expected result

```
import csv 
import glob

search_string = 'CAT'
state0 = '1101'
state1 = '1100'
state2 = '100'
corner1 = "TM"

with open("out.csv") as sample:
    reader = csv.reader(sample,delimiter="\t")
    header = 'ID', 'Code', 'state'

with open("out1.csv", "wb") as out1:
    writer = csv.writer(out1)
    writer.writerow(header)

    for path in glob.glob("out.csv"):
        if path == "out1.csv": continue
        with open(path) as fh:
            reader = csv.reader(fh)
           for row in reader:
               if corner1 in row:
                   if search_string in row:
                       if state0 in row:
                           readers = list(row)
                           readers.append(row[2])
                       elif state1 in row:
                           readers1 = list(readers)
                           readers1.append(row[2])
                       elif state2 in row:
                           readers2 = list(readers1)
                           readers2.append(row[2])
                           print(readers2)
                           writer.writerow(readers2)
                           break
```

Input.CSV

```
ID  Code    state
1   23456   1101
1   34567   1101
1   12354   1101
2   45632   1100
2   56798   1100
2   23412   1100
3   31276   100
3   98065   100
3   26987   100
```

Out.CSV (expected)

```
ID  Code    state           
1   23456   1101    23456   45632   31276
```

Comment: can you shorten your explanation and provide a [mcve]. I think you're not that far from that, but think of someone not having 1 hour to read your text.

Comment: I just edited my question. Appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: better, but the code isn't complete (we only see the loop), and it's not clear what out csv is: the result you're getting or the expected result? a [mcve] needs a little extra work.

Comment: @Jean Out.csv is the expected result.

Comment: those files are not really csvs. They are like pandas dataframes, or such. space-separated, not tab or comma separated. expected?

Comment: @jean. tbh with you I do not know much about pandas df. In my output I just want to write a single line on a csv file as shown in my sample output above.

Comment: I mean: if you are able to read those files using csv reader, then I need to see how you're opening/creating the readers. I would use a raw `str.split()` else.

Comment: using multiple spaces gives things like that `['ID', '', 'Code', '', '', '', 'state']
['1', '', '', '23456', '', '', '1101']
['1', '', '', '34567', '', '', '1101']` (lots of empty cells)

Comment: @Jean. Please see an update in my code.

Comment: the input file & output file _cannot_ be the actual inputs/outputs. `csv` module default delimiter is comma. You have to copy/paste the raw .csv data instead of a copy from excel or whatever.

Comment: The actual file I am reading from is a CSV file.  I updated my input.csv and output.csv with a .csv data.

Comment: ok the tabs show now. But it cannot work without `delimiter="\t"`: `csv.reader(sample, delimiter="\t")`

Comment: @Jean. Highly appreciate your feedback on this. I updated my code and reran. Still I am not getting expected output. What I am getting is 23456 23412 31276, expected is 23456 45632 31276 like the first code in each ID but for ID 2 in my code it is writing the code code in third line of ID 2 but for other 2 IDs it seems correct.

Comment: okay, I'll check that later tonight. Should be doable (if noone answers before)

Comment: Thanks. Badly stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to fix the broken logic of your attempt, but it's easy to write some clear code with correct logic, so I'll explain my code in details.

Your expected output is

```
title
full_first_row code1 code2 code3
```

You need:

- an empty `list` for the final row to write
- an empty `set` to memorize which ids have been already encountered

I would just read the rows and check if row id is already in the `set`. If not store ids in the `set` so it cannot be accounted for next time it appears.

If id is 1, copy the whole row in the output `list`. After that, append codes to this list.

Write the unique row made of this (bizarre) data after having copied the title from the input file.

Find below a self-contained example which uses a build-in list instead of an input file, but it's easy to replace `input_csv` by an actual file handle:

```
input_csv = """ID   Code    state
1   23456   1101
1   34567   1101
1   12354   1101
2   45632   1100
2   56798   1100
2   23412   1100
3   31276   100
3   98065   100
3   26987   100""".splitlines()   

import csv

with open("out.csv","w",newline="") as output_csv:
    cw = csv.writer(output_csv,delimiter="\t")
    cr = csv.reader(input_csv,delimiter="\t")
    cw.writerow(next(cr))   # write title
    found_ids = set()
    row_to_write = []
    for row in cr:
      if row:
        the_id = row[0]
        if not the_id in found_ids:
            found_ids.add(the_id)
            if the_id=='1':
                row_to_write += row

            row_to_write.append(row[1])
    cw.writerow(row_to_write)
```

Comment: Expected output is the same header as in the input and the first line that is ID 1 line in the input and then writing the codes for each ID in that line. Like all three codes . Please see below.

Comment: ok, I really thought there was a typo. This doesn't change much. Edited. I get the expected output & you get a fully rewritten code, because I don't get the broken logic of your attempt.

Comment: Highly appreciate it. After executing above script, the error I am getting is row_to_write.append(row[1]) , list index out of range. Any comments on that ?

Comment: Added a filter to discard empty rows of your file. But you must have rows with missing info, no doubt. Try on a small example file first.